# Probability: No of ways to win if you have n dice with m faces each

Tags: algorithm, math, probability

You are given a number of dices n, each with a number of faces m. You roll all the n dices and note the sum of all the throws you get from rolling each dice. If you get a sum >= x, you win, otherwise you lose. Find the probability that you win.

I thought of generating all combinations of 1 to m ( of size n ) and keeping count of only those whose sum is more then x . Total no of ways are m^n

After that its just the divison of both.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[EDIT: As noted by jpalacek, the time complexity was wrong -- I've now fixed this.]**

You can solve this more efficiently with dynamic programming, by first changing it into the question:

**How many ways can I get at least x from n dice?**

Express this as f(x, n).  Then it must be that

f(x, n) = sum(f(x - i, n - 1)) for all 1 <= i <= m.

I.e. if the first die has 1, the remaining n - 1 dice must add up to at least x - 1; if the first die has 2, the remaining n - 1 dice must add up to at least x - 2; and so on.

There are m terms in the sum, so if you [memoise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) this function, it will be O(m^2*n^2), since it will be required to do this summing work at most (m * n) * n times (i.e. once per unique set of inputs to the function, assuming that the first parameter x <= m * n).

As a final step to get a probability, just divide the result of f(x, n) by the total number of possible outcomes, i.e. m^n.

Comment: Your analysis is slightly flawed: To calculate `f(x,n)`, you need to calculate more than `m*n` function values (rather something like `x*n`, but surely less than that). So in the end it will result in something like `O(x*n*m)`

Comment: @jpalecek: Good catch, thanks.  Assuming x <= n*m (since otherwise the answer is trivially 0), a bound of O(m^2 * n^2) should be OK -- I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add up on @j_random_hacker's basically correct answer, you can make it even faster when you note that

f(x, n) = f(x-1, n) - f(x-m-1, n-1) + f(x-1, n-1)   if x>m+1

This way, you'll only spend `O(1)` time calculating each of the `f` value.

Comment: Very nice, +1! Had to stare at it for a while before it clicked: all the terms in the sum I gave are shared with the calculation for the previous value of x except for the first and last, so just subtract and add them respectively.

Answer (score 1):

//Passing curFace value will disallow duplicate combinations 
//For 3 dices - and sum 8 - 2 4 2 and 2 2 4 are the same combination - so should be counted as one

```
int sums(int totSum,int noDices,int mFaces,int curFace,HashMap<String,Integer> map)
{

    int count=0;

    if (noDices<=0 || totSum<=0)
            return 0;

    if (noDices==1)
    {
         if (totSum>=1 & totSum<=mFaces)
             return 1;
         else
             return 0;    
    }
    if (map.containsKey(noDices+"-"+totSum))
        return map.get(noDices+"-"+totSum);

    for (int i=curFace;i<=mFaces;i++)
    {

        count+=sums(totSum-i,noDices-1,mFaces,i,map);
    }

    map.put(noDices+"-" +totSum,count);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: I’m trying to wrap around your answer. Why would you want to add your “curFace” as one of your function’s arguments when you don’t really know what is your initial curFace? Sorry, I just found this out and typing on the phone at the moment.